# Using BeautifulSoup to find nested elements of a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image: Example tree]

I have this example of nested tables inside divs and I need to return all rows from all tables.  My current code is only returning the first set of rows.  When I try to use .find_all(), I get this error:

> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you
> call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

```
table_rows = soup.find_all('div', class_='table-responsive-sm')
    
if table_rows is not None:

    table_rows = table_rows.find_all('tr')

    for row in table_rows:
        #do stuff
```

I've tried using `.find()` and `.find_all()` on both the initial div and its children, but I get the same error. I think I need to use recursive search, but can't find any good documentation/examples.

How do can I return all rows from all tables on the page?

Comment: Why not just search for all `<tr>` elements directly?  I think it's safe to assume the only place those would occur is inside a table...

Answer (score 0):

table_rows contains a list of all the divs found here:

```
table_rows = soup.find_all('div', class_='table-responsive-sm')
```

Use something like this:

```
 tr_list = []
        for div in table_rows:
            for tr in div.find_all('tr'):
                tr_list.append(tr)
```

With that, you are going through the list of `div's` inside `table_rows`, extracting a list of `tr's`, going through that new list and attributing each `tr` to the `tr_list`.

EDIT:
You can make the code above into a single line using list comprehension, just make sure all that is happening is clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

`find_all()` returns a ResultSet which contains all matching elements.  ResultSet objects do not have a `.find_all()` method, as the error says.

What you actually wanted to do was iterate over each `<div>` element in the result, and then call `.find_all()` on each of *those* elements:

```
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='table-responsive-sm')
    for tr in div.find_all('tr'):
        # do stuff
```